# How to optimize MySQL queries and decrease server load?

Tags: php, mysql, join, count

My db tables look like that

First table:

[image]

Second table - lastsrvc (Last service info). id column -uniques auto-incremented id for every issue. 'cid' column - company's id. It's the link column between 2 tables: main and lastsrvc.

[image]

Now,  what I want to do is, lets say, count all issues for company 1. My code sends before while 1 query and fetches all rows of main table. Then sends second query within while for every company's row.

If in the future there will be 10 000 company's it will load server I think. Is there any way to send 1 query instead of sending query for every company (within while)? Is it possible to use COUNT before while, instead of second query within while?

My code looks like that

```
    <?php
    $query=$db->query("SELECT * FROM main");
    while($row=$query->fetch_object())
    {?>
        <tr> 
        <td><?=$row->id;?></td>
        <td><?=$row->company;?></td>
        <td><?=$row->address;?></td>
        <td><?=$row->contact_name;?></td>
        <td><?=$row->contact_phone;?></td>
        <td><?php 
        if ($row->warr)
        {
            echo 'Var,'.$row->warr_year.' il';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Yoxdur';
            }
        ?></td>
        <td>
        <?php
        if ($query2=$db->query("SELECT * FROM lastsrvc WHERE cid='$row->id'"))
        echo $query2->num_rows;
        ?>
        </td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: not doing queries in loop would already improve performances a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this as your top-level (and only) query:

```
SELECT main.id, company, address, contact_name, contact_phone, COUNT(cid) as cnt
FROM main
LEFT JOIN lastsrvc ON main.id = lastsrvc.cid
GROUP BY main.id
```

One single query with a join is almost always going to be much more efficient than running 1+n queries. You just echo out that 'cnt' field as usual:

```
<td><?php echo $row->cnt ?></td>
```

Comment: Is it important to declare column names one by one? I mean, can i use "SELECT *" instead of "SELECT main.id, company, address ..."?

Comment: It's a bit safer. You'll know exactly which fields you're getting, and in which order. Doesn't matter too much if you do want them all, but if you don't need them all, then don't waste disk/cpu/network bandwidth by fetching fields you don't need.

Comment: Ok, thx so much. I'd like to stay in touch with you. thx again

Answer (score 2):

Do a JOIN

```
SELECT main.etc, main.etc ..., COUNT(*) AS total
FROM main
LEFT JOIN lastsrvc ON main.id=lastsrvc.cid
GROUP BY main.id;
```

---

When the data becoming bigger, use pagination to fragment the result.
As the larger HTML return, browser also cannot *take it*
(Imagine a page more than 10Mb is hard to load properly in browser)

---

You can also stored the results into cache, such as into memcache.
The benefits of cache is avoid excessive query to database

Comment: Thx for fast reply. I got 1 question: Is it important to declare column names one by one? I mean, can i use "SELECT *" instead of "SELECT main.etc, main.etc  ..."?

Comment: Common practices is to avoid `*` cause is included every data. Selective column could be reduce amount of data returned.

Answer (score 0):

In *addition* to the other answers, you can also set indices on the columns you're joining on and filtering to speed up queries later on.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html